# vue front-end flask back-end integration

Tags: flask, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

Below is my vue front-end build(`npm rum build` on vue-cli 3).

[image]

And below is my `run.py` file for flask back-end.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


class CustomFlask(Flask):
    jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
    jinja_options.update(dict(
        variable_start_string='%%',
        variable_end_string='%%',
    ))


app = CustomFlask(__name__,
                  static_folder="./dist",
                  template_folder="./dist"
                  )


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

as you can see, I've changed default flask static, template directory to `./dist` due to my dist structure. But when I try to test my app, I got below messages.

**Chrome console**

```
vendor.97db904d.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
app.9aaff056.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
app.197e53a9.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
vendor.97db904d.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
app.9aaff056.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
app.197e53a9.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

**flask**

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018 19:44:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018 19:44:21] "GET /js/vendor.97db904d.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018 19:44:21] "GET /js/app.9aaff056.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018 19:44:21] "GET /css/app.197e53a9.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018 19:44:21] "GET /js/vendor.97db904d.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018 19:44:21] "GET /js/manifest.ce28c628.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018 19:44:21] "GET /js/app.9aaff056.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

How can I change properly static/template directory on flask? or should I change my build configuration on vue-cli3(webpack)? I have no more clue on this. Please give me a hint if you can. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `vue-cli` build to put the content of the `dist` folder in the  `Flask static` folder that would work.
However you'll need to change the way you initialize `Flask app` and serve `index.html` file.

```
# vue-flask.py   

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')


@app.route('/')
def index():

    # changed to send_static_file
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Here is the project structure:

[image]

I used the same approach in case of `react` and `Flask` integration but ended up splitting it down to two microservices as described [here](https://testdriven.io/).

Comment: It works like a charm! `static_url_path=''` and `app.send_static_file('index.html')` was key point. I will check and study your link, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [this example](https://codeburst.io/full-stack-single-page-application-with-vue-js-and-flask-b1e036315532) in an app recently and it worked very well.

In particular the paragraph about configuring the redirects.